# Cordova for android: An error occurred while listening android targets

Tags: android, cordova

I have read all the questions for the same problems and I have tried everything but nothing is working for me when I try to add android platform for cordova.

```
c:\Apps\fapp>cordova platform add android
Creating android project...

C:\Users\Andrej\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: An error occurred while listing Android targets
    at C:\Users\Andrej\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\lib\check_reqs.js:
87:29
    at _rejected (C:\Users\Andrej\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\node_mo
dules\q\q.js:808:24)
    at C:\Users\Andrej\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.j
s:834:30
    at Promise.when (C:\Users\Andrej\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\node
_modules\q\q.js:1079:31)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\Andrej\.cordova\lib\android\cor
dova\3.4.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:752:41)
    at C:\Users\Andrej\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.j
s:574:44
    at flush (C:\Users\Andrej\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\node_module
s\q\q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\Andrej\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\c
ordova\src\superspawn.js:112:23)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:5)
```

- Project is created using **cordova create fapp com.fapp Fapp**
- System is windows 8
- ANT, JAVA (JDK 1.7.0_51 and JRE7),  Android SDKs are installed from (17-19.0.3) and Android APIs (17-19)
- All environment variables for JAVA, ANDROID and ANT are set as well as path to bin for all of them into Path variable.

I really tried everything but keeps throwing this problem.

EDIT:

- Answer here did not help:
  [cordova ubuntu: An error occurred while listing Android targets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21699585/cordova-ubuntu-an-error-occurred-while-listing-android-targets)
- Permissions are set to Everyone full control and same issue

**FINAL SOLUTION**

- Finally I re-installed JDK and Android SDK and now everything works even it is still mystery to me.

Comment: whats your project name? means folder or directory name ?

Comment: or check this article, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21699585/cordova-ubuntu-an-error-occurred-while-listing-android-targets

Comment: I edited queston to answer your comments. So : "cordova create fapp com.fapp Fapp"
Also I tried that answer on SO and calling "check_reqs" just returns "An error occurred while listing Android targets"

Comment: Sometimes it may cause problem due to write permission on your drive. Have it somewhere else like D:/ or something..

Comment: Sorry, what to have somewhere else? Cordova installation is automatically installed there. To change android path?

Comment: no no just create your project outside C:/

Comment: Same issue. Even tried to give full permissions to Everyone and same issue.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had the same issue and solved it by setting the following **environment variables**:

- `%JAVA_HOME%` points to the root of your java installation (not the bin directory). In my computer it is: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0`. To test that it is configured correctly, open a new terminal and type `javac`. It should run the java compiler and shouldn't complain that it doesn't know the command. Please note that environment variables are only set when opening a new terminal (at least on windows) so every time you change something you have to open a new terminal.
- `%ANT_HOME%` point to the root of where you've installed Apache ant. In my computer it is: `C:\Users\User\apache-ant-1.9.3`. Test it by running the `ant` command. It shouldn't complain that the ant command is unknown to your machine. Remember to open a new terminal after setting the path and then try running ant.
- `%ANDROID_HOME%` points to where you have installed your android SDK. For example: `C:\Users\User\android\sdk`. Then try typing `emulator` to make sure it is installed correctly.

When all of these variables are set, you can use them in the **PATH** environment variable :

`%PATH%` contains the following entries: `%ANT_HOME%\bin;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools;%JAVA_HOME%\bin`

On windows 8 you can configure path and variables by right clicking on the start button, choosing system, and then *advanced system settings* and clicking on environment variables button. Remember to define the above environment variables above PATH. I defined everything in the *user variables* and it works just fine.

Comment: thanks, typing emulator command is a good test case and helped me solve problem. interestingly i added "%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools" before many of the folders and it worked. if i type it at the end of the Path it doesn't work. i don't know why.

Comment: I don't know really. My %PATH% is exactly in the order I pasted in the answer and it's working. But thanks for sharing this. Maybe someone else has the same problem and they can try it.

Answer (score 5):

-Possible solution for those who encounter this error

I had this error and it did relate to the path variables. I thought I had everything set correctly, but I was missing a portion.

First check by typing the command android into command line. If the SDK isn't opened you have not set the variables and/or path correctly.

You should have 3 (or 4 if you have separate android ones) variables.

```
ANT_HOME, JAVA_HOME and ANDROID_HOME
```

ANDROID_HOME should point to the sdk. If you (like I did) downloaded the bundle which includes eclipse, you need to have this variable point to the sdk folder inside the android bundle folder, not the android bundle folder itself (eg. C:\Dev\adt-bundle-windows\sdk)

You need to add `%ANDROID_HOME%\tools` and `%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools` to your path. Along with the link to the ANT `bin` folder and jdk `bin`.

I strongly urge you to triple check that all variables are correctly set AND that all four parts are added to the path.

Answer (score 1):

Please Refer the Question

[An error occurred while listing Android targets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23466479/error-an-error-occurred-while-listing-android-targets)

and the Link
developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds-cmdline.html

Most probably the path variable pointing to this android was wrong. 
I had used %ANDROID_HOME% as variable and scaled the same to path variables %ANDROID_HOME%\SDK\TOOLS. This method doesn't work. Experimentally resolved by directly pointing to the Tools and Platform Tools.

Just based on what I did and it worked for me. Hope You get the Issue resolved.

Comment: I (also?) found that using the %ANDROID_HOME% setting didn't work; adding the full path instead worked fine

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with version 3.5.0.

The problem is, that the error message from the script `check_reqs` located in `C:\Users\{yourUserName}\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.0\bin`, is not forwarded correctly.

I run the mentioned script manually and got the following error message:

> [Error: Please install Android target 19 (the Android newest SDK). Make sure you have the latest Android tools installed as well. Run "android" from your command-line to install/update any missing SDKs or tools.]

So basically to solve this issue you have to install the latest Android SDK.

Answer (score 0):

This link http://spring.io/guides/gs/android/ + running cmd as an administrator solved that issue for me.

This confirms Michael Brooks' assumption that this issue has to do with permissions settings on the Windows OS.  https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-cli/issues/77