# Phonegap Error: "An error occurred while listing Android targets" while installing Phonegap on Ubuntu

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-3, cordova-plugins

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide

As metioned in the above doc, I have already installed the required software for Phonegap as I have getting versions:

For Java:

> ```
> $ java -version java version "1.7.0_51" Java(TM) SE Runtime
> ```
>
> Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
>   (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)

For ANT

> ```
> $ ant -version
> ```
>
> Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on December 3
>   2011

For Node.JS

> ```
> $ npm -version
> ```
>
> 1.4.3

Now, the problem is when I create a phonegap project for Android like this "$ cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld", it creates the project directory with "hello" name.

But now, when I enter this command "$ cordova platform add android" in "hello" directory, it gives me the error given below:

> /hello$ cordova platform add android Creating android project...
>
> /home/deep/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:126
>                       throw e;
>                             ^ Error: An error occurred while listing Android targets
>       at /home/deep/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/lib/check_reqs.js:87:29
>       at _rejected (/home/deep/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:808:24)
>       at /home/deep/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:834:30
>       at Promise.when (/home/deep/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:1079:31)
>       at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/home/deep/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:752:41)
>       at /home/deep/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:574:44
>       at flush (/home/deep/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
>       at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13) Error: /home/deep/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/create: Command
>   failed with exit code 8
>       at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/superspawn.js:112:23)
>       at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
>       at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:5)

How to get out of this problem?

Answer (score 7):

I could fix this issue by following the [cordova-guide](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.5.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide). in short:

1. download the [adt-bundle](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)
2. unzip it to a location of my choice
3. add the named folders to the `PATH` variable:

   `export PATH=${PATH}:/home/me/opt/adt-bundle/sdk/platform-tools:/home/me/opt/adt-bundle/sdk/tools`

Answer (score 6):

hey man if you are using windows then you are missing environment variables. try this for this error:
"An error ocurred while listing Android targets"

1. go to My computer - right click - properties - advance system settings - environment variables.
2. add some variables needed, I did it like this

examples using my local scenario:

SDKHOME -> C:\development\AndroidADTBundle\ADT\sdk
JAVAJDK-> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\

1. Then update the PATH variable Like this: 
   ";%SDKHOME%\tools;%SDKHOME%\platform-tools;%JAVAJDK%\bin"

After doing then do your command, in my case is phonegap instead of cordova. And it should work: 
COMMAND: phonegap build android

let me know how it goes.

Comment: I can't upvote because the OP is requesting help for Ubuntu, not Windows, but this helped me.

Comment: no worries man. as long as it helps. Did you had it working? I have done this on windows and on Mac (is different between does. In windows I've done via the windows UI and on MAC via commmands). I don't think Ubuntu would be much different. Good luck dude!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, none of the previous anwsers works for me. The problem is that phonegap is not compatible with Android API 20.

First make sure you have setted all environment variables nedded:

```
export ANT_HOME=/usr/share/ant
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64"
export PATH=${PATH}:~/sdk/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702/sdk/platform-tools/:~/adt/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702/sdk/tools:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$ANT_HOME/bin
```

Go to the shell and run android, once there, check the API 19 and install it:

```
$ android
```

Now create a device from android avd using API 19 you have downloaded before:

```
$ android avd
```

Now try to add the platform to cordova:

```
$ cordova platform add android
```

Or check the requirements using cordova check script (~/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.0/bin/check_reqs)

Answer (score 2):

Have you downloaded the Android SDK?

try typeing the command 'android' in command-line or terminal

See the answer I typed out here:

[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23076010/3534641)

Answer (score 0):

try this one

install ant using brew

Download and install Homebrew by executing following command in terminal:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"
```

Install Apache Ant via Homebrew by executing

```
brew install ant
```

Run the PhoneGap build again and it should successfully compile and install your Android app.