# PhoneGap Android Run Issue on Windows

Tags: android, cordova

I tries to create new project using phonegap. The creation process i got one message as shown below :

Creation :

```
 [phonegap] missing library com.phonegap.helloworld/www/3.5.0
```

Is there any problem to the above statement.I didn't get any idea about this.I am new to phonegap.

Run Project issue :

```
D:\WS\myapp>phonegap run android

 [phonegap] detecting Android SDK environment...
    [phonegap] using the local environment
    [phonegap] adding the Android platform...
    Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:
            Path: platforms\android
            Package: com.phonegap.helloworld
            Name: HelloWorld
            Android target: android-19
    Copying template files...
    Running: android update project --subprojects --path "platforms\android" --targe
    t android-19 --library "CordovaLib"
    Resolved location of library project to: D:\WS\myapp\platforms\android\Cordo
    vaLib
    Updated and renamed default.properties to project.properties
    Updated local.properties
    No project name specified, using Activity name 'HelloWorld'.
    If you wish to change it, edit the first line of build.xml.
    Added file D:\WS\myapp\platforms\android\build.xml
    Added file D:\WS\myapp\platforms\android\proguard-project.txt
    Updated project.properties
    Updated local.properties
    No project name specified, using project folder name 'CordovaLib'.
    If you wish to change it, edit the first line of build.xml.
    Added file D:\WS\myapp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\build.xml
    Added file D:\WS\myapp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\proguard-project.txt

    Project successfully created.
    cp: no such file or directory: D:\WS\myapp\icon.png

    cp: no such file or directory: D:\WS\myapp\icon.png

    cp: no such file or directory: D:\WS\myapp\res\icon\ios\icon-72.png

    cp: no such file or directory: D:\WS\myapp\icon.png

    [phonegap] compiling Android...
    cp: no such file or directory: D:\WS\myapp\icon.png

    cp: no such file or directory: D:\WS\myapp\icon.png

    cp: no such file or directory: D:\WS\myapp\res\icon\ios\icon-72.png

    cp: no such file or directory: D:\WS\myapp\icon.png

    Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\li
    b\tools.jar
    Buildfile: D:\WS\myapp\platforms\android\build.xml

    -set-mode-check:

    -set-debug-files:

    -check-env:
     [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 22.6.3
     [checkenv] Installed at C:\Program Files\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-2014
    0321\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321\sdk

    -setup:
         [echo] Project Name: HelloWorld
      [gettype] Project Type: Application

    -set-debug-mode:

    -debug-obfuscation-check:

    -pre-build:

    -build-setup:
    [getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 19.1.0
         [echo] Resolving Build Target for HelloWorld...
    [gettarget] Project Target:   Android 4.4.2
    [gettarget] API level:        19
         [echo] ----------
         [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
        [mkdir] Created dir: D:\WS\myapp\platforms\android\ant-build
        [mkdir] Created dir: D:\WS\myapp\platforms\android\ant-build\res
        [mkdir] Created dir: D:\WS\myapp\platforms\android\ant-build\rsObj
        [mkdir] Created dir: D:\WS\myapp\platforms\android\ant-build\rsLibs
        [mkdir] Created dir: D:\WS\myapp\platforms\android\ant-gen
        [mkdir] Created dir: D:\WS\myapp\platforms\android\ant-build\classes
        [mkdir] Created dir: D:\WS\myapp\platforms\android\ant-build\dexedLibs
         [echo] ----------
         [echo] Resolving Dependencies for HelloWorld...
    [dependency] Library dependencies:
    [dependency]
    [dependency] ------------------
    [dependency] Ordered libraries:
    [dependency]
    [dependency] ------------------
         [echo] ----------
         [echo] Building Libraries with 'debug'...

    nodeps:

    -set-mode-check:

    -set-debug-files:

    -check-env:
     [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 22.6.3
     [checkenv] Installed at C:\Program Files\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-2014
    0321\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321\sdk

    -setup:
         [echo] Project Name: CordovaLib
      [gettype] Project Type: Android Library

    -set-debug-mode:

    -debug-obfuscation-check:

    -pre-build:

    -build-setup:
    [getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 19.1.0
         [echo] Resolving Build Target for CordovaLib...
    [gettarget] Project Target:   Android 4.4.2
    [gettarget] API level:        19
         [echo] ----------
         [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
        [mkdir] Created dir: D:\WS\myapp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\res
        [mkdir] Created dir: D:\WS\myapp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\libs
        [mkdir] Created dir: D:\WS\myapp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\ant-build
        [mkdir] Created dir: D:\WS\myapp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\ant-build\
    res
        [mkdir] Created dir: D:\WS\myapp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\ant-build\
    rsObj
        [mkdir] Created dir: D:\WS\myapp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\ant-build\
    rsLibs
        [mkdir] Created dir: D:\WS\myapp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\ant-gen
        [mkdir] Created dir: D:\WS\myapp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\ant-build\
    classes
        [mkdir] Created dir: D:\WS\myapp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\ant-build\
    dexedLibs
         [echo] ----------
         [echo] Resolving Dependencies for CordovaLib...
    [dependency] Library dependencies:
    [dependency] No Libraries
    [dependency]
    [dependency] ------------------

    -code-gen:
    [mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
    [mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
         [echo] Handling aidl files...
         [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
         [echo] ----------
         [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
         [echo] ----------
         [echo] Handling Resources...
         [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
         [echo] ----------
         [echo] Handling BuildConfig class...
    [buildconfig] Generating BuildConfig class.

    -pre-compile:

    -compile:
        [javac] Compiling 89 source files to D:\WS\myapp\platforms\android\Cordo
    vaLib\ant-build\classes

    BUILD FAILED
    C:\Program Files\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321\adt-bundle-windows-x
    86_64-20140321\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:601: The following error occurred while e
    xecuting this line:
    C:\Program Files\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321\adt-bundle-windows-x
    86_64-20140321\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:720: The following error occurred while e
    xecuting this line:
    C:\Program Files\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321\adt-bundle-windows-x
    86_64-20140321\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:734: Error running javac.exe compiler

    Total time: 1 second
    Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,ant,debug,-f,D:\WS\myapp\plat
    forms\android\build.xml,-Dout.dir=ant-build,-Dgen.absolute.dir=ant-gen
    { [Error: D:\WS\myapp\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat: Command failed wi
    th exit code 2] code: 2 }
       [error] D:\WS\myapp\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat: Command failed w
    ith exit code 2

    D:\WS\myapp>
```

I didn't get any idea about the above errors.So can you please suggest me what to do?

Comment: `craete` or `create`? It is suppose to be `create`

Comment: Oh sorry,Please see the my post once and what is that message?.@Diamond.

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22551453/phonegap-error-an-error-occurred-while-listing-android-targets-while-installi

Comment: Then also get error.So Please see once my post.@ Siddharth Vyas

Comment: Try with "cordova run android". http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface