# error running android in Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

I am having problem installing Phonegap android package. I looked at other stackoverflow questions but I am not clear what exactly the problem is. The error code I am getting is:

```
[phonegap] using the local environment
[phonegap] adding the Android platform...

C:\Users\chad\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:126

                throw e;
                      ^
Error: ERROR : executing command 'ant', make sure you have ant installed and add
ed to your path.
at C:\Users\chad\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.0\bin\lib\check_reqs.j
s:47:27
at exithandler (child_process.js:643:7)
at ChildProcess.errorhandler (child_process.js:659:5)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:95:17)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:807:12)
{ [Error: C:\Users\chad\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.0\bin\create.bat: C
ommand failed with exit code 8] code: 8 }
[error] C:\Users\chanukya\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.0\bin\create.bat:
Command failed with exit code 8
```

I found it is not required to install apache int if we have android sdk and java jre installed and their paths set. Please let me know if you get any clue. 
After installing ant and setting the path variables as shown below.

```
ANT_HOME = C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.9.4-bin\apache-ant-1.9.4
PATH = C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.9.4-bin\apache-ant-1.9.4\bin;
```

gives me

```
Files was unexpected at this time.
```

Could some one please let me know if there is something wrong with the path variables. Adding few more from cmd when I ran ant command

```
C:\Users\chan>if "C:\Users\chan" == "" goto homeDrivePathPre
C:\Users\chan>if exist "C:\Users\chan\antrc_pre.bat" call "C:\Users\chan\antrc_pre.bat"
C:\Users\chan>if "C:\Users\chan" == "" goto userProfilePre
C:\Users\chan>if "C:\Users\chan" == "C:\Users\chan" goto userProfile
Pre
C:\Users\chan>if "C:\Users\chan" == "" goto alpha
C:\Users\chan>if "C:\Users\chan" == "C:\Users\chan" goto alpha
C:\Users\chan>if "Windows_NT" == "Windows_NT"
C:\Users\chan>if "Windows_NT" == "WINNT"
C:\Users\chan>if "C:\apache-ant-1.9.4" == "" goto setDefaultAntHome
C:\Users\chan>if not _4 == _\ goto checkClasspath
C:\Users\chan>set _USE_CLASSPATH=yes
C:\Users\chan>rem CLASSPATH must not be used if it is equal to ""
Files was unexpected at this time.
C:\Users\chan>if ".;"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\lib\ext\QTJava.zip";C:
\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\lib\ext\QTJava.zip"=="""" set _USE_CLASSPATH=no
```

Answer (score 0):

Please install Ant and set the Ant path and SDK path in environment variables. also make sure you have updated SDK.

[Cordova for android: An error occurred while listening android targets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22275026/cordova-for-android-an-error-occurred-while-listening-android-targets/23307958#23307958)

Comment: I installed ant and now there is new problem "Files unexpected at this time". I know this is related to path problem. I checked my path and this is what I have.ANT_HOME=C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.9.4-bin\apache-ant-1.9.4 and PATH= C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.9.4-bin\apache-ant-1.9.4\bin;