# "cordova build" - error in Eclipse/Geany console

Tags: eclipse, cordova, build, ide

I'm currently trying to set up a Cordova 3.4 build environment, which easily (think hotkey) integrates into my development environment.

First try was to use Eclipse (4.3 Kepler) by following the sparse documentation, which did not result in a working configuration (deploying to emulator worked fine, but building failed).
Then I thought that it should be easy to run `cordova build` as an external tool within Eclipse, but sadly, then I got this error (as said the project just builds fine in the system shell):

```
[Error: An error occurred while listing Android targets]
Error: <Path-to-project>/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (<path-to-node-installation>/node-v0.10.26/node_modules/cordova/src/superspawn.js:112:23)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:5)
```

After giving up trying to setup Eclipse I finally thought that a simple text-editor should suffice since Eclipse only works for Android anyway, and you still need other "debugging" ides. I opted for Geany because of it's simple project management which just fits cordova's html, js and css very well; but still, I got exactly the same error as in Eclipse!

Solutions for this problem and tips on alternative workflows would be very appreciated (note that Geany has at least enough shell integration, so that I can easily open a shell in the Cordova project and execute the `build` from there – something seriously missing from Eclipse)

P.S.: The System is running Debian Wheezy

Comment: Debian Wheezy, edited the original post.

Comment: I get the same thing on Ubuntu 13.10, but it seems a dependency is missing somehow. Cf. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21699585/cordova-ubuntu-an-error-occurred-while-listing-android-targets)