# Error when build the phonegap android empty project?

Tags: android, ubuntu, cordova, phonegap-plugins, wikitude

I am trying to create a simple project in **phonegap** with association of **wikitude**.

This is the tutorial which I followed - [wikitude + phonegap tutorial](http://www.wikitude.com/external/doc/documentation/latest/phonegap/gettingstartedphonegap.html#getting-started-phonegap-plugin)

And I am using ubuntu 12.04 these are the only steps which I followed,

1. `$ npm install -g phonegap` - Adding phonegap
2. `npm install plugman` - Adding plugman
3. `sudo npm install -g cordova` - installing codova

Then following steps to create app,

1. `$ phonegap create MyAugmented` - create app
2. `$ phonegap build android` - build in android

Aditionally I have installed android sdk using `apt-get`.

But when I build this app using above build command it gives an error,

[image]

Error in Text :

```
Error: An error occurred while listing Android targets
    at /home/sachith/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/lib/check_reqs.js:87:29
    at _rejected (/home/sachith/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:808:24)
    at /home/sachith/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:834:30
    at Promise.when (/home/sachith/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:1079:31)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/home/sachith/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:752:41)
    at /home/sachith/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:574:44
    at flush (/home/sachith/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
{ [Error: /home/sachith/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/create: Command failed with exit code 8] code: 8 }
   [error] /home/sachith/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/create: Command failed with exit code 8
```

Answers would be really appreciated, 
Thanks in Advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probable reason is you don't have latest android SDK. So update your android SDK and it should work fine.

You can reference [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21699585/cordova-ubuntu-an-error-occurred-while-listing-android-targets) to see way of finding error.

> Cordova has a script to check if all dependencies are present. Is is
>   called when you run cordova platform add android but unfortunatly it's
>   output is not displayed when it fails.
>
> You can try to run it manually, it should be
>   $home/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/check_reqs
>
> The normal output when everything's fine is "Looks like your
>   environment fully supports cordova-android development!", oterwise it
>   should display a clear message about what's missing.
>
> Maybe your issue is that you havent't installed SDK platform for API
>   19 in android sdk manager (cordova 3.3 uses target sdk 19).

UPDATE:
Android SDKs are updated using SDK Manager. You can see how to use SDK from here.
http://developer.android.com/tools/help/sdk-manager.html

Comment: Ya it can be true. But I can not find how to do a update to existing version of the Android sdk to latest version. How can I do that?