# Cordova build android

Tags: android, ubuntu, cordova, ionic-framework

When I want to try *ionic weather app* (https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-weather/) I've got problems when I wanted to build android to my `phone-gap` application using **cordova**. I receive this message in terminal when I execute the command `cordova build android`

```
Error: An error occurred while listing Android targets
```

I work on ubuntu 13.10

Answer (score 0):

I was able to successfully build the project with the following steps:

```
npm install -g cordova ionic
git clone https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-weather/
cd ionic-weather
cordova platform add android
cordova build android
```

You may be missing the required android sdk tools, or they may not have been added to your system path.

Refer to this question

[cordova ubuntu: An error occurred while listing Android targets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21699585/cordova-ubuntu-an-error-occurred-while-listing-android-targets)

And follow [this guide](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide) to ensure your environment was setup correctly.

Comment: it is not the perfect solution of my problem