# ionic platform configure error : ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. I am trying to configure Ionic Framework. When I am trying to configure the platform for Android, I get the following error.

```
  /home/sameera/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.1/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                throw e;
                      ^
  Error: An error occurred while listing Android targets
  at /home/sameera/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.1/bin/lib/check_reqs.js:87:29
  at _rejected (/home/sameera/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.1/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:808:24)
  at /home/sameera/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.1/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:834:30
  at Promise.when (/home/sameera/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.1/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:1079:31)
  at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/home/sameera/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.1/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:752:41)
  at /home/sameera/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.1/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:574:44
  at flush (/home/sameera/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.1/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
  at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
  Error: /home/sameera/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.1/bin/create: Command failed with exit code 8
  at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:135:23)
  at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
  at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
  at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)
```

I also added Android to the `PATH` like below:

```
  export PATH=${PATH}:~/home/sameera/Downloads/Softwares/android-studio/sdk/tools
  export PATH=${PATH}:~/home/sameera/Downloads/Softwares/android-studio/sdk/platform-tools
```

Comment: Did ypu install all packages of android???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced same problem while configuring platform for Android. Maybe you don't have SDK platform for API 19 in android sdk manager (cordova 3.3 or 3.5 uses target sdk 19). Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21699585/cordova-ubuntu-an-error-occurred-while-listing-android-targets) answer for more.